# Relationship between the number of distinct conjugates of a set and its centralizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have a worksheet question which asks,

> If $G$ is a finite group and $S \subseteq G$, what is the relationship between the number of conjugates of $S$ and the order of its centralizer/normalizer?

Focusing on only the centralizer, I know that for any $x \in S$, the size of the conjugacy class of $x$ is equal to $\frac{|G|}{|C_{G}(x)|}$. This follows from the orbit-stabilizer theorem if we let $G$ act on itself by conjugation.

Then I think $C_{G}(S) = \bigcap_{x \in S} C_{G}(x)$.

Also, the size of the set of all distinct conjugates of $S$ should be the size of the largest conjugacy class from the elements in $S$.

So $|conj(S)| = \max_{x \in S} |conj(x)| = \frac{|G|}{\min_{x \in S} |C_{G}(x)|}$ and $|C_{G}(S)| = |\bigcap_{x \in S} C_{G}(x)| \leq \min_{x \in S} |C_{G}(x)|$.

Then combining the equations, I get $|conj(S)| \geq \frac{|G|}{|C_{G}(S)|}$. This seems a little imprecise, though. Can I do any better?

Comment: Can you apply the proof of the orbit-stabilizer theorem to the whole of $S$ and get your desired result straight away?

Comment: Okay, if I let $G$ act on the power set of $G$ by conjugation, then I get $|conj(S)| = \frac{|\mathcal{P}(G)|}{|C_G(S)|} = \frac{|G|^{|S|}}{|C_G(S)|}$. Is this the correct approach? I am not sure if conjugation is a group action on the power set of a group (I defined the 'action' of $g$ on $S$ by elementwise conjugation.)